# How can I refresh value kendo numerictextbox?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have a kendoNumericTextBox. I have code that sets the value of the input element associated with the kendoNumericTextBox. For example, the code calls:

```
$('#myId').val('test');
```

Unfortunately, the kendo numeric text box doesn't automatically reflect the value. How can I tell the kendoNumericTextBox to update its value? I know there's a method on kendoNumericTextBox as follows:

```
$('#myId').data('kendoNumericTextBox').value('test');
```

However, I'm populating many fields and not exactly sure which ones will be kendoNumericTextBox fields. So, I prefer to call something like I do with the chosen plugin to refresh the value based on the underlying component. For example, with the chosen plugin, I can call:

```
$('.chosen').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

to update all values based on the underlying select component's value.

Comment: do you use remote data? we nee more info to help you

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question?

Comment: @James did any of these answers work for you? I know it is a long time ago, but I was just cruising through my SO Questions and Answers to clean anything up.

Answer (score 20):

```
var numerictextbox = $("#paymentAmount_" + id).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    numerictextbox.value("0.00");
```

This works for me.  Store the element in a variable and the set the value using double quotes. Also I was not able to put a word in like 'test' in a numericTextBox...I am assuming you meant that as test data. But this should work for you as well.

Answer (score 5):

i was having trouble with this same thing, I However got it working without the quotes...
all that i can say is that it seems to work for now....

```
 calCalories: function (e) {

        var totalCals = 0;
        totalCals = totalCals + ($("#Carbs").val() * 4);
        totalCals = totalCals + ($("#Protein").val() * 4);
        totalCals = totalCals + ($("#Fat").val() * 9);

        var numerictextbox = $("#Calories").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
        numerictextbox.value(totalCals);
    },
```

note:
one could obviously use the below line of code to get the value from the event

```
e.sender.value()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger change event for kendo numeric textbox

```
$('#myId').data('kendoNumericTextBox').trigger('change');
```